# Como trabalhar com URL absoluta?

Tags: htaccess, url, xampp

Estou desenvolvido um sistema e para realizar os testes eu tô utilizando o xampp. Ou seja, tudo fica acessível através do endereço:

> localhost/meusite/...

Para realizar a chamada de todos os links do meu site, bem como incluir arquivos, eu tô utilizando url absoluta, por exemplo:

> "localhost/nomedosite/pagina1.php"
>   "localhost/nomedosite/pasta/paginapasta.php"

Está tudo funcionamento perfeitamente, mas atualmente já são mais de 50 arquivos que eu desenvolvi, o problema disso tudo é que quando eu realizar a hospedagem, eu terei que reescrever cada link/include/chamada de cada arquivo? Existe alguma forma de eu realizar a escrita de url absolutas sem esse trabalho dobrado?

Eu pensei em usar url relativas, mas quando eu faço isso por causa do .htacess as urls acabam dando erro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você esta programando em PHP certo? Então você pode criar um arquivo chamado config.php e nele definir a BASE URL. Exemplo:

```
<?php
 define('BASE_URL','http:/localhost/nomedosite/');
```

E nos outros arquivos você só faz a chamada da configuração assim:

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');
?>
<html ...>
<body>
<a href="<?php  echo BASE_URL; ?>pasta/paginapasta.php">meu link para outro arquivo</a>
```

Ai quando precisar alterar a base só alterar o arquivo de configurações `config.php`.